# Usuage Of Eclipse for BB and Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

I am basically bb programmer and i used NetBeans ,BB JDE for BB development.

I am partially switching over to android also.So i want to know how to use Eclipse IDE that should be compatible to Both Blackberry JDE and android SDK.

What is IDE' that needs to be downloaded

.I downloaded BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_1.0.0.67.exe.

I have a doubt of adding JDE's to IDe and i want to know whether can i load the android SDK to this Eclipse IDE

Version: 3.4.1
Build id: M20080911-1700

Any Ideas will be useful

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Eclipse for both Blackberry and Android development at the same time with no conflicts or issues. Your set up should work well.

I suggest using the Blackberry Update-Site to get the plugin installed:

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/eclipseplug_updatesite.jsp

Comment: Hi, i tried two things
1)I have downloaded the eclipse for android and i tried to add the BB to it,it shows error on installing.
2)Similarly i tried the viceversa,i downloaded the eclipse with BB plugin and i tried installing the android and i was partially sucessful,But the pblm i face is that i cannot create new emulators of Android 2.0 ,1.6 0r  1.5.It justs shows emulators of 1.6.I tried adding any emulators to it it,,it is showing only in Android SDK and AVD Manager,but it is not showing in the target list.Any Quick fix to it will be helpful.

Comment: Hello Guys,i cleared my problem,problem is that it's property was set to GoogleMaps API option,but after changing it to Google API 2.0,i can create 2.0 emulators.Thanks for your help\